# Laravel get specific amount of related model

Tags: laravel-5

Hi I have two models `Category,News`, i want to retrieve categories with 3 latest news in each category, `News` models have created_at column for date when it created.

Can i achieve this in laravel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm trying to load only the last 3 comments on every post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505673/im-trying-to-load-only-the-last-3-comments-on-every-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way,

```
 $news = Category::whereHas('news',function($query){
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3);
})->get();
```